# Fourier transform (properties)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have a function $f$ such that $|f(x)|\leq e^{-x^2/2}$ hence in $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})\cap\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$ and thus we can compute the Fourier transform
$$\hat{f} (\xi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) e^{-i\xi x} dx.$$

By Plancherel's theorem we know that
$$\int_{\mathbb R} |\hat{f}(\xi)|^2 d\xi = \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|^2 dx\leq \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x^2}dx \leq \sqrt{\pi} $$
where the last follows from the fact that $|f(x)|\leq e^{-x^2/2}$.

But actually I want to prove more. I would like to see if:
$$\int_{\mathbb R} |\frac{\hat{f}(\xi)}{\xi^2}|^2 d\xi \leq C$$
for a positive finite constant $C$. How do I proceed? Is there a way to prove it using Plancherel's theorem? Btw! If it makes things easier we can assume that $f$ has compact support :)

Thanks!

Comment: Note that it is even more: $f\in\mathcal{L}^2\cap\mathcal{L}^1$. That is important in order to state: $\hat{f}(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)e^{-i\xi x}dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take $f\left(x\right)=\exp\left(-x^{2}/2\right)$ you have $$\hat{f}\left(\xi\right)=\exp\left(-\xi^{2}/2\right)$$hence $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{\hat{f}\left(\xi\right)}{\xi^{2}}\right|^{2}d\xi=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\exp\left(-\xi^{2}\right)}{\xi^{4}}d\xi=\infty.$$

Comment: I did exactly the same now :) and realized it's not possible. Thank you very much!